# Как кастомизировать 404-ю ошибку

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как можно кастомизировать 404-ю ошибку при помощи `*.htaccess` файла в `ВЕБ`-сервере `Apache`? Сам `404.htm`l лежит в папке `/errors/404.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В .htaccess

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
```

Собственно добавить больше нечего :)

Comment: Неужели все так просто? ))

Comment: именно так :)